# Proper way to split Python list into list of lists on matching list item delimeter

Tags: python

```
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', '', 'd', 'e', 'f', '', 'g','h','i']

def chunk(list, delim):
    ct = list.count(delim)
    chunks = [[]] * (ct+1)
    for iter in range(ct):
        idx = list.index(delim)
        chunks[iter] = list[:idx]
        list = list[idx+1:]
    chunks[ct] = list
    return chunks

print chunk(list, '')
```

Produces:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

Which is what I want, but I feel like this is the 'c' way to accomplish this. Is there a more pythonistic construct I should know?

Comment: don't use `list` as a variable name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it [using `itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
[list(v) for k, v in groupby(l, key=lambda x: x!= '') if k]
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c', '', 'd', 'e', 'f', '', 'g','h','i']
>>> ch = [list(v) for k, v in groupby(l, key=lambda x: x!= '') if k]
>>> ch
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

Comment: That looks very pythonistic! I checked out the linked documentation but I must confess I don't understand how it works.

Comment: Hang in there.. You will get it :-). Data is evaluated in a "lazy" fashion in python. That is what you see.

Comment: What happens if the array starts or ends with `''` ?

Answer (score 1):

Focusing on the iterability of lists in Python:

```py
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', '', 'd', 'e', 'f', '', 'g','h','i']

def chunk(list, delim):
    aggregate_list = []
    current_list = []

    for item in list: 
      if item == delim:
        aggregate_list.append(current_list)
        current_list = []; 

        # You could also do checking here if delim is starting 
        #  index or ending index and act accordingly 
      else:
        current_list.append(item)

    return aggregate_list

print chunk(list, '')
```

Answer (score 1):

A neat one-liner:

```
L = ['a', 'b', 'c', '', 'd', 'e', 'f', '', 'g','h','i']
new_l = [x.split("_") for x in "_".join(L).split("__")]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
lists = ['a','b','c','','d','e','f','','g','h','i']
new_list = [[]]
delim = ''
for i in range(len(lists)):
    if lists[i] == delim:
        new_list.append([])
    else:
        new_list[-1].append(lists[i])

new_list
[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.  Code-only answers are discouraged.